# Is there any workaround to run JDK 1.7 on Solaris SPARC 5.8?

Tags: java, solaris, sparc

I have to work with some outdated Solaris servers. They can run JDK **1.6**.

```
SunOS 5.8 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
```

I know that JDK **1.7** requires Solaris **10+**, but I have no chance to upgrade these servers :(

When trying to run JDK 1.7, I got this error

```
Error: failed /opt/jdk7/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so, because ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/jdk7/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so: symbol __fmodf: referenced symbol not found
```

I have no luck with Google.

Comment: You can try to [build OpenJDK from source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html).

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/ss11-patches-140390.html I'm trying to apply the patch for Math library.

Comment: Yeah, sunsolve is gone. The patches are likely on My Oracle Support, http://support.oracle.com . https://blogs.oracle.com/patch/entry/resolving_stale_links_to_sunsolve